# Cannot supply Id from javascript variable to an apex attribute

Tags: javascript, slds

```
<script>
   var idForDropDown = someValue;
</script>        
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="'+ idForDropDown + '">
</ul>
```

When I check the id it takes `idfordropwdown` as a string and not assigns the value it has in javascript. Can someone tell what is the mistake I am doing?
thanks.

Comment: Where's the "apex attribute"? All I see here is some generic HTML. You may want to just ask this question on [so] instead, or [edit] this question and make it more relevant to salesforce.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify markup values using JavaScript you have to execute JavaScript code in the client browser. (The HTML text has already been generated on the server.)

The code could be something like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
</ul>

<script>
var idForDropDown = someValue;
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')[0].id = idForDropDown;
</script>
```

See documentation such as [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Fairly unusual to be setting an id like that though.

If the id value can be worked out when the page is generated on the server (before it is passed to the client browser) and you were using Visualforce this would work because the id value is merged into the HTML text:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="{! idForDropDown  }">
```